# Poner el nombre de un post dentro de un enlace externo en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

Estoy tratando de generar un sitio web que simula una tienda en Wordpress, usando **Jet Engine** y **Elementor Pro**. El asunto es que necesito generar un link que se llene dinámicamente con el nombre del post para que se abra una página externa **que contenga el nombre del post y se pueda mandar a WhatsApp**.

Lo que debo hacer con ese link es ponerlo en un botón en Elementor Pro.

El link que necesito generar es de esta forma:

[https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+571234567890&text=Hola%2C%20me%20interesa%20averiguar%20sobre%20el%20producto%20[el_nombre_del_post]](https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+571234567890&text=Hola%2C%20me%20interesa%20averiguar%20sobre%20el%20producto%20%5Bel_nombre_del_post%5D)

El resultado que busco es que se genere un mensaje, siempre al mismo número, que diga "Hola, me interesa averiguar sobre el producto XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" (Donde las X son el nombre del post).

He buscado en san google y no he podido encontrar nada. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no es muy difícil de hacerlo, pero tendrás que modificar el loop del archive, dentro del while puedes usar la función `get_the_title()` y concatenarlo con tu enlace de whatsapp, debería de ser mas o menos asi.

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        $whatsappLink = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+571234567890&text=Hola%2C%20me%20interesa%20averiguar%20sobre%20el%20producto%20' . get_the_title();

        echo '<a href="' . $whatsappLink . '">Link de whatsapp</a>';

    endwhile;
```

Eso debería de imprimir tu enlace con el nombre del post

Otra forma seria hacerlo con un shortcode, no uso page builders por lo que si estas usando uno no sabria decirte si esto funcionara, pero puedes probar con esto.

```
function whatsappMessage() {

    $whatsappLink = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+571234567890&text=Hola%2C%20me%20interesa%20averiguar%20sobre%20el%20producto%20' . get_the_title();
    return '<a href="' . $whatsappLink . '">Link de whatsapp</a>';

}
add_shortcode( 'ws_button', 'whatsappMessage');
```

Solo tienes que usar el shortcode [ws_button] pero esto es asumiendo que el page builder deje al shortcode ingresar al while, si no funciona puedes probar a agregar el id manualmente, con algo como esto

```
function whatsappMessage( $atts ) {

    $whatsappLink = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+571234567890&text=Hola%2C%20me%20interesa%20averiguar%20sobre%20el%20producto%20' . get_the_title( $atts['id'] );
    return '<a href="' . $whatsappLink . '">Link de whatsapp</a>';

}
add_shortcode( 'ws_button', 'whatsappMessage');
```

Entonces el shortcode quedaría así: [ws_button id="55"], cambias el 55 por el id de tu post.

El código debes de agregarlo a el archivo functions.php o bien en un plugins de snippets.

Comment: Gracias! Justo lo que me hacía falta!! Elementor sí me permite algo como eso...